# Issue on hiding multiple columns with NatTable

Tags: eclipse-plugin, nattable

I need to programmatically hide multiple columns of a NatTable.
To do that, I compute an array of indices with a method and then I
invoke the MultiHideCommand as follows.

```
int[] indexArray = idxToHide.stream().mapToInt(i -> i).toArray();
_tableView.doCommand(new MultiColumnHideCommand(_tableView,indexArray));
```

What I get is that only a bunch of columns are hidden, but not all the columns in the indexArray.

I read that the ColumnHideShowLayer has been designed with UI interaction in mind.

Is there a right way to programmatically remove multiple columns?

Answer (score 0):

First, the command takes the positions as parameter, not the indexes. Second, the positions need to be based on the layer that is used as first parameter. If a ViewportLayer is involved, non-visible columns won't be taken into account.

So you could try to calculate the positions based on some lower layer, e.g. the SelectionLayer, and then pass in the SelectionLayer and the positions based on the SelectionLayer on the command. That should work in theory.

Comment: Thank you Dirk, I was able to hide the columns using your suggestion. Now I'm trying to select a specific cell using the SelectCellCommand using both the viewport layer and the selection layer but in both cases the I can't select the right cell on the reduced column. Can the viewportlayer understand the exact cell to select if there are some hidden columns?

Comment: As said before, you need to pass the position and not the index and you need to pass the position related to the SelectionLayer. The ViewportLayer treats positions only for the visible area. So `_tableView.doCommand(new SelectCellCommand(selectionLayer, col, row));` should work.

Comment: Yes, I got that I need the position. I think there is something wrong in the way I get the column position on right click (I need to know the column position based on the right click for a feature of the application). To get the column position on right click, I use the `MenuItemProviders.getEventData(event).getColumnPosition()`. I pass that position to the SelectCellCommand with selectionLayer as first argument.

Comment: That's incorrect. The position you get this way is based on the NatTable, not the SelectionLayer. When used this way, you need to use the NatTable as first parameter of the command.